# Playing back an ima4 file

Tags: audio, playback, ima4

I am looking to record voice in as compact a file format as possible for an ipad app, and not concerned about sound quality.  I chose the ima4 format but don't really know much about audio, so am having trouble figuring out how to play back the produced file to test how it sounds.  Is this a compressed format that I have to uncompress with some tool in order to just listen to it?  Is this the right format if I want something compact and reasonably coherent but not worried about great quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to save it as an .aif, .aiff, or .aifc file which then was playable by common players like iTunes.